# behaviour of float in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   float f = 0.1;
   double d = 0.1;
   printf("%lu %lu %lu %lu\n", sizeof(f), sizeof(0.1f), sizeof(0.1), sizeof(d));
   return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./a.out 
4 4 8 8
```

As per above code, we can see `sizeof(0.1)` and `sizeof(0.1f)` are not same.
`sizeof(0.1) is 8 bytes`, while `sizeof(0.1f) is 4 bytes`.
but while assigning the `value to float variable f`, it automatically truncates its size to `4 bytes`.

While in below code, while comparing it with float x it is not truncating and `4 bytes of float` are compared with `8 bytes of 0.1`, value of `float x` matches with `0.1f` as both are of 4 bytes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float x = 0.1;
    if (x == 0.1)
        printf("IF");
    else if (x == 0.1f)
        printf("ELSE IF");
    else
        printf("ELSE");
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./a.out 
ELSE IF
```

why and how it is truncating while assigning and not while comparing?

Comment: The `float` type is a [*single precision* floating point type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), while `double` is a *double precision* floating point type. I also recommend you read ["Is floating-point math broken?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), it will help you understand why `0.1f != 0.1`.

Comment: Is there any way to tackle rounding off issue?

Comment: @NitinTripathi Never compare floating point numbers for equality and expect them to always be off by a small amount. You can also avoid this by not using the `float` type unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: **not using the float** will force us to use **double** which will be add **another overhead of 4 bytes** which is again not good programming practice :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A floating point literal without a suffix is of type `double`. Suffixing it with an `f` makes a literal of type `float`.

When assigning to a variable, the right operand to `=` is converted to the type of the left operand, thus you observe truncation.

When comparing, the operands to `==` are converted to the larger of the two operands, so `x == 0.1` is like `(double)x == 0.1`, which is false since `(double)(float)0.1` is not equal to `0.1` due to rounding issues. In `x == 0.1f`, both operands have type `float`, which results in equality on your machine.

Floating point math is tricky, read the standard for more details.

Comment: Thanks @FUZxxl, that was really helpful.
whatever you said in third para, i actually tried to implement it and found below:
`printf("%lu %lu %lu %lu\n", sizeof((double)f), sizeof((double)0.1f), sizeof((double)0.1), sizeof((double)d));
   printf("%15.15f %15.15f %15.15f %15.15f\n", (double)f, (double)0.1f, (double)0.1, (double)d);`

**Output:**
`$ ./a.out 
4 4 8 8
8 8 8 8
0.100000001490116 0.100000001490116 0.100000000000000 0.100000000000000`

If we see, all four are converted to 8 bytes by typecasting, but rounding issue occurs while typecasting from float to double.

Comment: @NitinTripathi something's wrong with your comment, `sizeof((double)x)` will always output `8` no matter what `x` is

Comment: Thanks @M.M for pointing out. correction as below

`printf("%lu %lu %lu %lu\n", sizeof((double)f), sizeof((double)0.1f), sizeof((double)0.1), sizeof((double)d)); printf("%15.15f %15.15f %15.15f %15.15f\n", (double)f, (double)0.1f, (double)0.1, (double)d);` Output: `$ ./a.out  8 8 8 8 0.100000001490116 0.100000001490116 0.100000000000000 0.100000000000000` If we see, all four are converted to 8 bytes by typecasting, but rounding issue occurs while typecasting from float to double.

Answer (score 2):

a floating point constant like `0.1` is a double unless specified as a float like `0.1f`. The line

`float f = 0.1;`

means create a double with value 0.1 and cast it to float and lose precision in the process. The lines

```
float x = 0.1;
if (x == 0.1)
```

will cause x to be implicitly converted to double but it will have a slightly different value than for e.g. `double x = 0.1;`

Answer (score 1):

0.1f (the "f" after the number) is for the computer as float , that how your compailer know that he need to store it as float and not as double.
so float 0.1 not equal to 0.1 , its equal to 0.1f

Answer (score 1):

when you write `0.1` , it is considered by default as `double`. suffix `f` explicitly make it float.

In second question float are stored as **ieee standard** so it it's going in `else if` because equivalent conversion of 0.1f to double is not same.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Answer (score 1):

`0.1` is a double value whereas `0.1f` is a float value. 
The reason we can write `float x=0.1` as well as `double x=0.1` is due to implicit conversions .

But by using suffix `f` you make it a float type .

In this -

```
if(x == 0.1)
```

is flase because `0.1` is not exactly `0.1` at some places after decimal .There is also conversion in this to higher type i.e `double`.

Converting to `float` and then to `double` , there is loss of information as also `double` as higher precession than `float` so it differs .